# Is a list always needed to do bindings? Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding

I want to make some rectangles with text in side them. Then of the People Hub when you look at contacts through a group.

I am wondering though I need to make X rectangles based on each item but I don't know how to make it repeat.

The only way I can think of is using a list and then trying to get rectangles with text in them.

I am unsure if I can make like repeating stack panels or repeating grids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what you want to do.

**If you have fixed number of items, and you know what they should look like designtime**

then you can simply add a `ListBoxItem` in XAML:

```
           <ListBox>
                <ListBox.Items>
                    <ListBoxItem>
                        <Border Background="Green" Width="70" Height="70">
                            <Grid>
                                <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" 
                                           Fill="Red" Margin="10" />
                                <TextBlock Text="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem>
                        <Border Background="Blue" Width="70" Height="70">
                            <Grid>
                                <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" 
                                           Fill="Yellow" Margin="10" />
                                <TextBlock Text="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                </ListBox.Items>
            </ListBox>
```

**If you don't know how many items there are in advance, and you want them all to have the same look**

then yes, binding is the only way to go

Depending on the complexity of the ui for a data bound item, you may want to wrap that ui logic in a separate (User)Control, and use that as the DataTemplate for the items:

```
           <ListBox ItemsSource={Binding TheItemsToBind}>
               <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DateTemplate>
                        <mycontrols:MySpecializedControl 
                            [...whatever it takes to bind to the data item...]/>
                    </DateTemplate>
               </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

A bound list per-se is not aware of what the element will look like in a `ListBox`. You need to define a `DataTemplate` for each item (more details [here](http://tonychampion.net/blog/index.php/2011/12/9th-day-of-silverlight-implicit-data-templates/)).

Now, since you're talking about grouping like it is done in the People Hub, you can use the `LongListSelector` control (tutorial [here](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api) and [here](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part2-data-binding-scenarios)).